# expect script stop after sending \003

Tags: shell, expect

Need some assistance on an expect script where it would not continue. The function of the script is to connect on remote hosts, change user then ran a command. But i place a else statement that when the change user prompts to update password it will just skip that and continue on the next host. However the script stops on the point where i send \003.The expect script is indicated below;

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set i [open "eposhosts"]
set hosts [split [read -nonewline $i] "\n"]

foreach host $hosts {
spawn /usr/bin/ssh -q appadm@$host
expect "appadm@$host:~>"
send "su epos\r"
expect "Password:"
send "password\r"
expect {
"epos@$host:/home/appadm>" {send "grep playlist /appl/epos/bin/cron.epos\r"; exp_continue}
"(current) UNIX password:" {send "\003"; exp_continue}
}
expect {
"epos@$host:/home/appadm>" {send "exit\r"; exp_continue}
"[appadm@$host ~]" {send "exit\r"}
}
expect "appadm@$host:~>"
send "exit\r"
expect eof
}
```

Comment: What do you mean the script stops? What happens exactly? The expect script exits entirely?

Comment: yes the expect  script exits in error

Comment: It exits with an error? Really? What error?

Comment: it doesnt say much but the error output is below

invalid command name "appadm@i200135"
    while executing
"appadm@$host ~"
    invoked from within
"expect {
"epos@$host:/home/appadm>" {send "exit\r"; exp_continue}
"[appadm@$host ~]" {send "exit\r"}
}"
    ("foreach" body line 11)
    invoked from within
"foreach host $hosts {
spawn /usr/bin/ssh -q appadm@$host
expect "appadm@$host:~>"
send "su epos\r"
expect "Password:"
send "ep0s05\r"
expect {
"epos..."
    (file "/appl/ops/web/merger/calendar/survey/eposexp2.sh" line 6)

Comment: @Dren, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask -- it seems obvious that you should have put the full error stack trace in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the error message, it looks like the problem is because of un-escaped open square bracket `[`.  If you want to match literal open square bracket, then it should be,

```
"\\\[appadm@$host ~]"
```

The reason is, `[` is special to both `Tcl` and `Expect`. Unless escaped, it will treated as a command call.

Change your code as,

```
expect {
    "epos@$host:/home/appadm>" {send "exit\r"; exp_continue}
    "\\\[appadm@$host ~]" {send "exit\r"}
```

}

Note : We don't need to escape the close square bracket.

Comment: only need a single backslash I think

Comment: @glennjackman : No Sir. When used inside double quotes, if we escape with only one backslash as  `expect "\[appadm@host ~]"`, it will become a glob pattern which can match any character among `appadm@host ~` (i.e. 'a' or 'p' or 'd' etc). OP's issue relies on matching literal open square bracket, which is why I have used 3 backslashes.

Comment: @Dinesh Thank you the added backslashes was able to receive the exit command. But it seems to continue on the next statements, with error below

send: spawn id exp7 not open
    while executing
"send "exit\r""
    ("foreach" body line 16)
    invoked from within

what i would like is this statement will let the script continue

"epos@$host:/home/appadm>" {send "exit\r"; exp_continue}

while this statement when met will end here and proceed on to the next host

"[appadm@$host ~]" {send "exit\r"}

should i add ; eof after the send "exit\r"?

Comment: @Dren : Sending `exit` at the first time itself, the session got closed it seems. You can add `eof` and remove further `expect` and `send` if eof is observed.

Answer (score 2):

The value `\003` is <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> (`^C`), which is likely to be an interrupt character on receiving terminal.  If `expect` sends that as expected, it can very well stop a program.

Responding to comment by @Dren:
If you send newlines, the change-password prompt will probably reject that (no empty passwords...) and will not stop your script.

For instance

```
{send "\n\n\n"; exp_continue}
```

rather than

```
{send "\003"; exp_continue}
```

Comment: yes i specifically insert control C because i want to skip the change password prompt when asked and move to next host. do you have a way to skip that other than ^C?

Comment: do you meant i should instead use below
set hosts [split [read $i] "\n"]
instead of
set hosts [split [read -nonewline $i] "\n"]

when i did this it still exit out